# Запятые при соединенных союзом "и" вложенных списках

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая в предложениях, подобных:

> Он ел пряники и пироги и пил чай.

Первое и в одном списке, а второе - в другом. Мне кажется, запятая перед вторым союзом и не нужна, поскольку в каждом списке лишь один.

Comment: Вот еще пример, где запятые не нужны. «По улице бродили кошки и собаки и прыгали голуби и воробьи»

Answer (score 5):

Никаких запятых не требуется, потому что однородные члены относятся к разным группам: *пряники и пироги*, *ел и пил*.

Comment: любопытно, есть ли насущная необходимость в использовании в ответе местоимения **никаких**

Comment: "Никаких " подразумевает  ни перед первым, ни перед вторым союзами.

Answer (score 0):

В таком написании запятые не нужны, но так не очень правильно писать, т.к. сложно сразу понять какое слово к какой группе относится. Это стилистическая ошибка - желательно избегать разнородных повторяющихся союзов в предложении (например, так: "он выбежал из-за камня из-за меня" (he ran from stone becase of me) - грамматически верно, стилистически - нет). 
Лучше сформулировать так: "Он ел пряники, пироги и пил чай".